# Storing chrome extension options without closing options modal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have a chrome extension with options set through the `options_ui` tag in manifest.json. I can save options however I noticed the options modal has to be closed for the `chrome.storage.sync.set` function to complete saving the options. How do I force saving of the options upon clicking "save" even if the options modal is not closed?

options.js:

```
function save_options() {
  var hideAds = document.getElementById('hideAds').checked;

  chrome.storage.sync.set({
        hideAds: hideAds
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options successfully saved...';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 1000);
  });
}

// Restores checkbox state using the preferences stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  // Use default values
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
        hideAds: false
  }, function(items) {
        document.getElementById('hideAds').checked = items.hideAds;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Redesign",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding background.js code below that doesn't get latest options (after clicking save button on the options page) unless options modal is closed. The `alert` line below outputs the old saved option value...and the new saved value only after the options modal is closed.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.storage.sync.get(['hideAds'], function(items) {

                if(typeof items.hideAds !== 'undefined') {
                   hideAds = items.hideAds;
                   alert(hideAds);
                }
            })
            doSomething(tab);
        }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think the options won't be saved until you close the modal?

Comment: Added background.js code above which outputs the old option value until the options modal window is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged) event in background page ( you would never need to listen to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` for getting storage value), which fires when one or more items change:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, areaName) {
    if(areaName === 'sync') {
        const hideAdsChange = changes['hideAds'];
        if(typeof hideAdsChange !== 'undefined') {
            const newValue = hideAdsChange.newValue;
            console.log(newValue);
        }
    }
});
```